# Android best revision control for apps?

Tags: java, android, version-control

Ok so I have my app that I am about to release as a beta. It also has bug reporting feature thanks to [**ACRA**](http://code.google.com/p/acra).

Now I want to be updating the beta and also fix any bugs that has been reported.
But of course I would want to keep the original released copy so that I can figure out the bugs and what not.
And then as final versions get released I would want to do the same with each released version.

So I need some kind of version control system. I am new to all this so I'm not sure what the best/simplest way to go about doing so.

I'v googled around and there seems to be numerous revision control systems with a lot of features I don't really need.
But as long at its easy to do what I'm looking for I'll be happy with it. I am also using eclipse so something that goes great with it would be nice.

I'm not too sure how it would all work so any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Eclipse, and all Eclipse projects are using Git, you could use that DVCS (Distributed Version Control System) with your project.

[image]

See [Eclipse and EGit: Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html), combined with the [Git Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Git/article.html).

[alt text http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/images/repositoryview10.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/images/repositoryview10.gif)

Note: this [other tutorial](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/dvcs-install-gitegit-and-mercurialhgeclipse/) introduces both EGit, and Mercurial (other DVCS) plugins.
So you have the choice..